# Apache service keeps restarting everytime I refresh my page

Tags: apache, refresh

The project is based on LAMP. Recently I noticed that every time I refresh a PHP page, the httpd service will restart. I use `ps aux | grep httpd` command to track the status of the httpd. Every time I refresh a page in the browser, and print the process list, I will find the line

`/usr/local/httpd/bin/httpd -k restart`

One very weird thing is that the `error_log` does not have any logs for this restarting.

How to I go about troubleshooting this to determine the cause?

Comment: Does the process have the same PID every time you look?

Comment: Does it happen on all the pages in your app or just some?

Comment: all pages, no matter .html page or .php page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced a similar issue a couple a months ago, it was due to a miss-configuration of the MPM module. Apache was not able to create a worker thread.

Did you change any configuration related to this ?

Here is a sample of what I got in my log files:

```
[mpm_worker:alert] [pid 16077:tid 3077421936] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
```

If you changed anything related to MPM, try reverting to default values and see if it works.

Comment: From the process list I can tell multiple httpd processes are spawned whenever I restart the httpd service. And every time I refresh a page, all the processes restart, and the log file doesn't have anything for these restarting

Comment: I finally got rid of this problem. I think it's indeed the incorrect configuration of MPM. After the reconfiguration, the problem is gone. Thank you.